# Having difficulty with a php and ajax register and login page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having some problems with my code and need some help. I am trying to create a register form that the user can input a username and password to sign up. I want to use `ajax`, but when I incorporate it it doesn't seem to work. To test it, I have echoed `"hi from php"` but it doesn't show in the browser when I hit register with no fields filled in. The document names bellow are called

- index.php
- register.js
- register.php

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
        var user = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();


        var data = "user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;

            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "register.php?",
                data: data,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $("#register_output").html(data);
                }

        }); 
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="register.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>

        <p>use the form below to register</p>

        <p>
        <div id="register_output"></div>
        </p>

        <p><strong>Username</strong></p>

        <p><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"></p>

        <p><strong>Password</strong></p>

        <p><input id="password" type="password"></p>

        <p><button id="register">Register</button></p>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo "hi from php";
?>
```

here is the video that i followed  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSLm4NlMkvo&t

Comment: You have return false before $("#register_output").html(data); removing it may solve your problem

Comment: when i remove that it still doesnt show. i wasnt suppose to leave that in when i asked the question.

Comment: maybe you are returning an error, have you checked the response with chrome debugging tool "network"?

Comment: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Hasan/Desktop/Test/register.php?: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4

Comment: i have already posted an answer to your question

Comment: i have posted a link of a youtube video bellow which i was following. i wanted it to be the same as that. it is when he adds the echo in the register.php is when i have the problem and doesnt function like his.

Comment: you just miss the name attribute in your form fields

Comment: what do you mean lelio?

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to send XHR request from file viewing ( `c:/path/to/file.php` which doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

1 - you have a `return` statement which stops the function for continuing, if you removed that, it should work.

2 - also you may have an error , make sure to check the developers tools, and add `.fail` function to handle errors like `404` or `503` HTTP errors.

3 - make sure to include the protocol at the beginning  of your url suck as `https://` or `http://`

here's  an example

html/jquery:

```
<form id='register'>
<div id='response'></div>
<input name='name' placeholder='name' />
<input name='password' placeholder='password' />
<button id='button' onclick="register();"> submit</button>
</form>
<!-- import jquery here -->
<script>
function register() {
var data = new FormData($('#register'));
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://example.org/register.php",
  data: data
})
  .done(function(html) {
    $( "#response" ).append( html );
  })
  .fail(function(html) {
    alert( "error" );
  });
      return false;
}

</script>
```

register.php

```
 <?php
   // do something here
   print_r($_REQUEST);

 ?>
```

**UPDATE**

i came to understanding that you are trying to send XHR requesting from file viewing `c:/path/to/your/file.html`, and you can't do that ! you need a server and its not hard, the first thing to do is to install xampp and put your files in `c:/xampp/htdocs/test/` and you should be able to do that, but if you are already using `xampp` or simpler tool the answer is above

Comment: in the youtube video that i was following he hadnt used a server yet. So how comes when i do it i wiould need to use xampp?

Comment: @fehmiE you need to install a webserver and php in order to run php directives and as `http://localhost` and not directly in your web browser as `file:///` which I think is what you're trying to do here.

Comment: So what do you suggest that i do because i am new to this type of coding. Could you give me like examples like applications or how to view it from local host?

Comment: follow tutorials on how to install `xampp` it includes apache2 webserver, mysql ( mariadb ) and php. all you need to test a php application on localhost